# what excel formula to extract whole rows that contain a certain word from spreadsheet

Tags: macos

What Excel formula should I use to extract whole rows that contain a certain word from the spreadsheet?

I have a large spreadsheet with 7 columns and 100 rows. I need a separate spreadsheet in that workbook to pull all rows and their data that contain the word FC in Column F.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As long as your version of Excel supports filters;

1. Click the filter button, so you can filter columns.
2. Filter column F for only 'FC' (you may need to do a containing text filter)
3. You should now have a filtered table with the information you want and you can now copy and paste that wherever you like

Comment: You can also set filters and do the copy/paste via VBA code if you need a full automation.

Comment: Don't forget to mark as the answer if it was the answer to you question